# How to style ul horizontally

Tags: css

I'm trying to list form labels and button horizontally.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.viewLayout ol{
width: 1px;
float:left;
}
.viewLayout ol > li{
direction:ltr;
display: inline;
}
.viewLayout input[type=button] {
display:block;
width: 100px;
color:#FFF;
background-color: #808285;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
height:22px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Result of my code:
[image]

How to style the edit buttons to be inline with the office area ?
meaning

Comment: So you want each office to show on a separate row, and the edit button next to the area?

Comment: Stop using an <ol> if you don't want items on new lines.

Comment: I want the numbering also @Takendarkk

Comment: @Rhumborl Yes please

Comment: @Takendarkk If semantically you want a numbered list of items, thenyou should use `<ol>`. Whether you show it on separate lines or not you can control with CSS. They are not mutually-exclusive.

Comment: @Rhumborl But if this OP is in such beginning stages it would just be easier to type a 1, then 2, then 3, rather than coerce a list into displaying horizontally with css. I will wait for the css answer you post and compare its ease of use to what I suggested.

Comment: @Takendarkk Such an interesting idea, thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `width: 1px;` property from `ol` description. And, obviously, `display:block` from `input` description.

UPD: interesting, but my browser doesn't render your code as your picture. Precisely, `display:inline` in `li` description breaks the markup. It should be removed.